# In the movie Contact, what are the various soundbites that we can hear during the opening scene?

Tags: contact

In the [intro](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EWwhQB3TKXA) of the movie *Contact*, we can hear various soundbites: some music, people speaking, theme from TV series like *The Twilight Zone*, and so on.

Is there a list somewhere of what  all the soundbites used for this scene are?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

IMDB's Trivia section contain(ed) this list.

> - "[Semi-Charmed Life](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=beINamVRGy4)" by Third Eye Blind
> - "[Wannabe](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gJLIiF15wjQ)" by The Spice Girls
> - "[God Shuffled His Feet](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0aqlS9SOkjs)" by Crash Test Dummies
> - "[Angry Days](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QW0Ae742ZKk)" by Lagwagon
> - "[Obviously a major malfunction...](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c5FQFnbWJ2c)" - Challenger Shuttle disaster
> - The [theme to "Dallas](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PsBYBugvDek)" (1978)
> - "[Disco Inferno](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A_sY2rjxq6M)" by the Tramps
> - "[Sometimes You Feel Like A Nut...](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CjVKUap1HgU)" - Chocolate bar commercial
> - "[Funkytown](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RVwiixXViT0)" by Lipps Inc.
> - Richard Nixon's "[I am not a crook](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sh163n1lJ4M)" speech
> - [Walter Cronkite announcing the assassination of President Kennedy](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6PXORQE5-CY)
> - Neil Armstrong's "[One Small Step](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HCt1BwWE2gA)" speech
> - "[Yellow Polka Dot Bikini](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ICkWjdQuK7Q)"
> - "[I Have A Dream...](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vP4iY1TtS3s)" a Martin Luther King Jr. speech
> - [Theme from "The Twilight Zone](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XVSRm80WzZk)"
> - [Transition music from "Seinfeld"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EP2GMyQdw78)
> - "[Broken Wings](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nKhN1t_7PEY) [by Mr Mister, presumably]
> - Senator McCarthy's infamous interrogation question ("[Are you now or have you ever been...](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FDC4Keawv6U)")
> - Douglas MacArthur's "[Old soldiers never die...](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tuagi9kZe8A)" quote
> - Franklin Roosevelt's 8 December 1941 address to Congress ("[a date that will live in infamy](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lK8gYGg0dkE)")
> - [Theme from The Lone Ranger](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p9lf76xOA5k) (1949)
> - Song "[We're In the Money](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UJOjTNuuEVw)"
> - [Opening speech by Adolf Hitler](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V4clb83HBeU) at the German Olympics, being the transmission in history that was aired with sufficient power to escape the Earth's atmosphere.
> - [White Bird](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XUNgQ03D2qA) by It's A Beautiful Day
> - "[Nel blu dipinto di blu](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7wWiC0e3b2I)" also known as "Volare" by Domenico Modugno
> - "[Boogie Oogie Oogie](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TJxkdgYUoJU)" by Taste of Honey
> - "[Somewhere Over the Rainbow](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PSZxmZmBfnU)" sung by Judy Garland
> - [Theme to "The Andy Griffith Show](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S_xFuWmdhLk)"
> - "[Please, Mr. Postman"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=425GpjTSlS4) by the Marvelettes